# How to detect exceptions in release mode in flutter

Tags: flutter, proguard

My flutter app works fine on debug and profile builds but crashes on release build. I would like to understand why it crashes on release build. Is there any way to see exceptions like I can see in debug mode? It is not enough to see print logs which I can see print logs and does not help. I need to know where and why the app crashes. So it would be helpful if I can see exception logs. I suspect insufficient pro guard rules causes this problem but I don't know which rules should I add more. If I can see exception log, this would help me to add correct rules to pro guard.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your physical device or use any emulator and then run your app using this command `flutter run --release` from the terminal. You'd be able to view the logs in the release mode

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use third party tool to track production exceptions. I recommend Sentry (I am not employee, just happy user) as it is easy to configure and works out of the box.

Check https://pub.dev/packages/sentry package and https://sentry.io/ for documentation.

Please note that Sentry works ONLY at production. Also note that if your app crashes, the **error is logged next time you try to open the app**, and not immediately after the crash.